# JavaScript Smart Date Filtering

Tags: javascript

I have an array of some dates that have gaps in them.  I want to be able to get the first day of each month in my dataset, given that gaps may fall on the 01 day of the month.

What is the best way to do this?

dates are in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

```
dates = [10/31/2014, 11/03/2014, 11/04/2014, 11/05/2014, ...]
```

I want the result of the filter to be 11/03/2014, which is the first day of Nov 2014 that is contained in my data set.  Weekends are omitted from the data set in this example.

But assuming my data set is large and continues with more gaps, I want to find the first day of every month.

Comment: not clear. please post a sample. what you have and what you'd like it your result of filter to be.

Comment: The question is too confusing to understand. Please provide your detailed code if possible.

Comment: "I want to be able to get the first day of the month in my set" in this case the first day would be the 1st or "01" a constant, I assume this is not what you mean. If you want the `DD` value of a date in format of `MM/DD/YYYY` you could just say `variableNameHere = arrayNameHere[index].substr(3, 2);` assuming the array is an array of strings such as `arrayNameHere = { "01/07/2015", "12/17/2012", "02/11/2013" };` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(list, month) {
    var monthdates = list.filter(function(e,i,a) {    
        if(Number(e.split("/")[0]) == month)
        return e;
    });
    var leastdateofmonth = monthdates.reduce(function(p,c,i,a) {
        var pd = Number(p.split("/")[1]);
        var cd = Number(c.split("/")[1]);
        if(pd < cd)
            return p;
        else
            return c;
        });
    console.log(leastdateofmonth);
}
 //call it like this
foo(["10/31/2014", "11/03/2014", "11/04/2014", "11/05/2014"],11);
```

Test results:

```
[anupam@localhost ~]$ node sortmonth.js 
11/03/2014
```

Call the function for each month and append it to a "leastdate" list. Here I called it for month 11.

Also consider, using a callback instead of returning, so that nothing gets blocked.